# how it`s possible to include a file (include();) from the root folder to a files from different subfolders?

Tags: php, url, path, include

how it`s possible to include a file (include();) from the root folder to a files from different subfolders ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use relative path from your script with `../` or use absolute path with the help of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT`] as Col. Shrapnel suggested.