# PHP include files from different subdirectories within the root folder

Tags: php, html, css, image, include

My question is similar to [PHP include file strategy needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339202/php-include-file-strategy-needed). I have the following folder structure:

```html
/root/pages.php 
/root/articles/pages.php
/root/includes/include_files.php 
/root/img/images.jpg
```

All pages in the "**/root**" and "**/root/articles**" directories have a "header.php" and "footer.php" file included within them, which are stored within the "**/root/includes**" directory.

The header and footer pages both contain images stored in the "**root/img/**" directory.

As suggested by:

[how it`s possible to include a file (include();) from the root folder to a files from different subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423098/how-its-possible-to-include-a-file-include-from-the-root-folder-to-a-files)

[How to use a PHP includes across multiple directories/sub directories with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488267/how-to-use-a-php-includes-across-multiple-directories-sub-directories-with-relat)

I tried the `**dirname**` solution and the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]` solution to include the header and footer in the files stored in the **root** directory and **articles** subdirectory.

However, I run into issues when I try and use either method (within the header and footer files) to link images:

```
<img src=" <?php echo dirname(__FILE__). '/img/image.jpg';?>">
```

Chrome fails to display the images and throws the following error:

> **locally:** Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/root/img/image.jpg
>
> **on the server:** GET http://host.com/home/public_html/root/img/image.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have checked the URL's and they appear to be correct. Having googled for solutions, I found that chrome prevents the display of files that contain it's complete file path for security reasons.

How do I get around this? or is there an alternative way to include files (including images) into files stored in any subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sandeep's answer is partially right. because

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

will again give back fully qualified path to the root.

```
<img src=" <?php echo 'http://localhost/favicon.ico';?>"/>
```

will return image back because now I am not giving it local path as per your problem but url of the server I am running.

Answer (score 1):

for your included scripts try setting the `includes_path` using `set_include_path`

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
```

Then, to include a script within your pages you can use:

```
include( 'script.php' );
```

For the images, prefix the path with a leading slash `/` ~ ie:

```
<img src='/img/image1.jpg' />
```

It tends to be easier to use root relative paths rather than directory relative paths so prefixing with the leading slash means a folder within the root.

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/image.jpg';
<img src="<?=$url?>">
```

Comment: that didnt resolve it. I run into the same issue. doesnt let me open the file with file:// protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use ../img/image.jpg for including in files inside /root/articles.

Use img/image.jpg for including in files inside /root